# Zerar posição de um vetor para garantir que não há sujeira

Tags: c++, array

Como eu faço para zerar a posição de um vetor do tipo inteiro, por exemplo, para garantir que não haja "sujeira" quando alocar a posição na memória no C++?

Alguma função da linguagem ou um algoritmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se vai usar *array* mesmo, basta fazer isto:

```
std::fill_n(array, 100, 0);
```

Alguns compiladores podem adotar uma sintaxe alternativa extra:

```
int array[100] = {0};
```

ou

```
int array[100] = {};
```

ou

```
int array[100] = { [0 ... 99] = 0 };
```

Teste qual produz o resultado no seu compilador se quiser uma delas. Mas isso é fora do padrão, então deve ser evitado.

Se quiser adotar o jeito C de fazer isso (não recomendo):

```
int array[100];
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));
```

Mas em C++ o *array* não é tão recomendado, prefira:

```
std::vector<int> vector1(100, 0);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Vector/Initialization.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

Apenas esclarecendo que **arrays são diferente de vectors!**

Em C++, O meio mais fácil de zerar corretamente um **vector** é usando seu próprio método:
Precisa do Header:

```
#include <vector>
```

Um vector de int com 5 Elementos

```
std::vector<int> Numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Aqui vc limpa seguramente o vector inteiro acima criado

```
Numbers.clear();
```

Para arrays SIMPLES você pode usar:
Declarando da forma abaixo eu atribuo o valor 0 para todos os 5 números:

```
int Numbers[5] = {0};
```

Ainda em arrays SIMPLES não faça isso em vectors!!!
Você pode atribuir ZEROS usando memset. Forma correta de usar!

```
memset(&Numbers, 0, sizeof(Numbers));
```

Answer (score 0):

É um caso em que eu gosto bastante de usar uma macro... mas no fundo é um loop:

```
#define INIT_ARRAY(array,value) {\
    for(s32 i=0; i<lSIZEOF(array);i++){\
        array[i] = value;\
    }\
}
```

Com isso eu posso fazer INIT_ARRAY passando o array e o valor com o qual eu quero inicializar.